# Clang and g++ treat operator overload differently?

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, rvalue

I am using C++14 (-std=c++1y on both g++ 4.9.1 and clang 3.5).

To start, here is Exhibit A (where the Foo namespace exists):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace Foo
{
    struct A
    {};
}

void operator<<(std::ostream &os, Foo::A const &a)
{}

int main()
{
    Foo::A a;

    std::ostringstream() << a;

    return 0;
}
```

Both Clang and g++ barf on this, although for different reasons.

---

Exhibit B (where there is no Foo namespace):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct A
{};

void operator<<(std::ostream &os, A const &a)
{}

int main()
{
    A a;

    std::ostringstream() << a;

    return 0;
}
```

g++ still barfs, but Clang successfully compiles.

Is this reasonable to expect?  What's going on here?

Comment: I have seen a couple of comments about binding temporary values to a non-const reference.  Two points I would make:  First, by changing the code above to be void operator<<(std::stream const &os, Foo::A const &a) {} it STILL does not work.  Second:  The namespace is what's causing the issue I think, because if you take struct A out of the Foo namespace (put it at global scope) then my version works fine.

Comment: @NeilKirk I think you accidentally compiled the (working) lvalue version.  It's the rvalue one that I'm having troubles with.

Comment: When the left operand of operator<< is an rvalue, the actual overload that gets called is [`std::operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), which takes a `basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&&`.

Comment: @NeilKirk and I have found this to be a difference between Clang and g++.  When struct A is NOT in a namespace, Clang will compile the code and g++ will not.  When struct A is in the Foo namespace, neither compiler likes it.

Comment: This is a _library_ issue. It's libstdc++ vs libc++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the standard supplies a catchall `operator<<` for rvalue output streams ([ostream.rvalue])

> ```
> template <class charT, class traits, class T>
> basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
> operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os, const T& x);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: `os << x`
>
> *Returns*: `os`

(There's also a matching `operator>>` for rvalue input streams - see [istream.rvalue].)

This is the `operator<<` that gets called.

Second, as is usual for templates, in the body of this function template, the unqualified lookup for `operator<<` in `os << x` is done in the template definition context, which doesn't have your `operator<<` available. Instead, your overload must be found by ADL, which, in turn, means that it must be in the same namespace as `A`.

Your second version should compile, and in both cases the compiler did find your overload just fine. The problem is that libstdc++'s implementation (which boils down to `return os << x;`) is non-conforming, because it assumes that `os << x` must return `os`. There's no such requirement.

**Edit**: The libstdc++ bug report is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65543); it has since been fixed in trunk and the fix has been backported to the 4.8 and 4.9 branches.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to bind a temporary object to a non-const reference. In this case `std::ostringstream()` creates a temporary object and tries to bind to the non-const reference parameter of `operator<<`

Comment: I can get it to compile by ONLY removing struct A from the Foo namespace (i.e., just put it at global namespace and then change Foo::A to A in the operator<< signature)

Comment: @Badmanchild Are you sure? Can you provide ideone link for that?

Comment: I'll put it on there -- one second

Comment: Hmmmm you are correct -- I put it on ideone and got the same error as you.  This appears to be a difference between g++ and clang then....  Is this something C++14-ish that clang has implemented but g++ has not yet gotten around to?  Or is clang in error when it compiles this code?

Comment: I also compiled locally with g++ and got the same error as you did, so it's not an issue with ideone.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that when I put struct A in the Foo namespace (and so Clang also barfs), the error is NOT because of binding temp obj to non-const ref.  Instead, Clang just cannot find a suitable function to handle those arguments.

Comment: I edited the question to more accurately reflect what you helped me to find out (namely, that it's a g++/clang thing).  Thanks for that!

Comment: Encountered the same error. Make sure to add `const` in the function declaration!